# BeautifulSoup4 python3.6 impossible to get data in middle of the screen

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I'm a Japanese chess player and I would like to plot popularity of a strategy in function of time. To do that, I have a website database with a link for the first strategy called Yagura:
https://shogidb2.com/strategy/%E7%9F%A2%E5%80%89/page/1
What I would like to do is to store the years that appears at the beginning of each game (like this I can store it, then count). In this page "2017". But, it is impossible to get the text information. I also tried to find the web links to get data from the game page... But the links don't appear...

Here is my code, if you have any tip, you are welcome, I start to be crasy ^^

```js
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def downloadString(url, params = {}, cookies = {}):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    data = requests.get(url, params = params, headers = headers, cookies = cookies)
    return data.text
    
url = "https://shogidb2.com/strategy/%E7%9F%A2%E5%80%89"
html_doc = downloadString(url, params = {}, cookies = {})
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
      
links = []
      
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
  print(link.get("href"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the website is built with `ReactJS`, it creates VirtualDom to populate the data. BeautifulSoup on the other hand looks for DOM elements. Since DOM is not created for the elements, it will get null values. **The best solution is to use `casperjs`** (http://casperjs.org/)

The only reason I'm suggesting something like `casperjs` is much simpler to use than python supported scraping modules like `selenium`. If you are very serious about your pythonic way, `Selenium` should work for you. But its hard to configure first time.

Do install **phantomjs** and **casperjs** with `npm install -g phantomjs casperjs`.

PS: Phantomjs is used by casperjs, its just a dependency of casperjs.

```
// scrape.js
var casper = require('casper').create();
var links;

function getLinks() {
// Scrape the links from top-right nav of the website
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href')
    });
}

// Opens casperjs homepage
casper.start('https://shogidb2.com/strategy/%E7%9F%A2%E5%80%89');

casper.then(function () {
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.run(function () {
    for(var i in links) {
        console.log(links[i]);
    }
    casper.done();
});
```

To run the script: `casperjs scrape.js`

Comment: If you are really serious about using , python `Selenium` should work for you.  I can update Selenium implementation if you need, but its tough to configure selenium for the first time

Comment: Thank you to point out this. Because I'm not a web coder, I was basicaly thinking that when you have HTML, you can investigate the code like a txt file. I had some look at the Selenium tool, I'll try this way. Thank you !